# Not getting desire output from function using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql

I have created small function using T-SQL which takes one input parameter as phone number and returns area code from it. Function compiles successfully but getting only first digit of the phone number instead of three digits.

Refer below code:-

```
create or alter function getareacode (@phoneno as nvarchar)
returns nvarchar(10)
with schemabinding 
as
begin
  declare @areacode as nvarchar(10);
  select top(1) @areacode = value from string_split(@phoneno,'-');
  return @areacode;
end;

select dbo.getareacode( N'123-456-789');
```

Comment: `LEFT(@phoneno, PATINDEX('%-%', @phoneno)-1)` can also get you everything before the first `-`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(@phoneno as nvarchar)`  will generate the 1st character only

try

```
(@phoneno as nvarchar(50))
```

However, the split may not be necessary

Try the following.  It may be more performant

```
Declare @S nvarchar(50) = '123-456-789'

Select left(replace(replace(replace(@S,'-',''),'(',''),')',''),3)
```